# Use Wireshark to see Paypal requests

Tags: paypal, wireshark

Is this possible, I tried filtering by HTTP and SSL, but no luck. In SSL there are a lot of requests.

I also tried HTTPS, but is not even a protocol.

I am doing requests through a Ruby Gem, does this matter?

Maybe is better to debug requests in another point. What would you suggest me?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, "HTTPS" is not a protocol.  It is, instead, the HTTP protocol transported atop the SSL protocol.

In order to see what's being transported atop SSL, you will need to supply enough information to allow Wireshark (or *whatever* packet sniffer you're using, if it even *supports* dissecting SSL) to decrypt SSL; one of the reasons why SSL exists is to make it difficult to read it with a packet analyzer!

See [the Wireshark Wiki page for SSL](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL) for more information on how to get Wireshark to attempt to decrypt SSL traffic.

> Maybe is better to debug requests in another point.

If you're making the Paypal requests from a browser, there might be a plugin for your browser that lets it capture HTTP traffic *before* it gets encrypted over SSL.  I think [FiddlerCap](http://www.fiddlercap.com/FiddlerCap/) is a plugin for Internet Explorer to do that; [there might be some other tools to do that as well](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=web%20browser%20traffic%20capture%20plugin&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).